# What is the fastest way to calculate the dot product of two f64 vectors in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am writing an implementation of a neural network in Rust and am trying to calculate the dot product of two matrices. I have the following code:

```
fn dot_product(a: Vec<f64>, b: Vec<f64>) -> f64 {
    // Calculate the dot product of two vectors.
    assert_eq!(a.len(), b.len());
    let mut product: f64 = 0.0;
    for i in 0..a.len() {
        product += a[i] * b[i];
    }
    product
}
```

This takes two vectors, `a` and `b` (of the same length) and carries out element-wise multiplication (multiplying value 1 of vector `a` with value 1 of vector `b` and adding this to value 2 of vector `a` and with value 2 of vector `b` and so on...).

Is there a more efficient way of doing this, and if so, how?

Comment: Looks fine to me. I'd use it until you're confident it's a bottleneck. If you're already sure you need the fastest possible, maybe look into [SIMD](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/rust-2018/simd-for-faster-computing.html)?

Comment: You can do it in one line with iterators, like `a.into_iter().zip(b).map(|(a, b)| a*b).sum()`. But I'd expect that to be comparably fast, not significantly faster (or slower).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't meant as a comprehensive general answer, but I wanted to share a little code.

Your implementation looks pretty much like what I would do unless I knew it was the bottleneck in my application. Then I'd look into more esoteric approaches (maybe [SIMD](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/rust-2018/simd-for-faster-computing.html)).

That said, you might consider changing your function to take slice references instead. That way you can pass `Vec`s or arrays:

```
fn dot_product(a: &[f64], b: &[f64]) -> f64 {
    // Calculate the dot product of two vectors. 
    assert_eq!(a.len(), b.len()); 
    let mut product = 0.0;
    for i in 0..a.len() {
        product += a[i] * b[i];
    }
    product
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", dot_product(&[1.0,2.0], &[3.0,4.0]));
    println!("{}", dot_product(&vec![1.0,2.0], &vec![3.0,4.0]));
}
```

See also:

- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Answer (score 0):

I used `rayon` and `packed_simd` to calculate the dot product and
found a way to be faster than Intel MKL:

```
extern crate packed_simd;
extern crate rayon;
extern crate time;

use packed_simd::f64x4;
use packed_simd::f64x8;
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::vec::Vec;

fn main() {
    let n = 100000000;
    let x: Vec<f64> = vec![0.2; n];
    let y: Vec<f64> = vec![0.1; n];

    let res: f64 = x
        .par_chunks(8)
        .map(f64x8::from_slice_unaligned)
        .zip(y.par_chunks(8).map(f64x8::from_slice_unaligned))
        .map(|(a, b)| a * b)
        .sum::<f64x8>()
        .sum();
    println!("res: {}", res);
}
```

[This code in my Github](https://github.com/ChingChuan-Chen/dot_product). I hope this helps.

Comment: It's not needed to have `use std::vec::Vec;`; it's part of the prelude. Why is the time crate here? Can you compare this to the performance of the OPs code and the other answer? Why the choice of `unaligned`?

Comment: I looked at this benchmark in more depth and I don't think it is representative or should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at [@Ching-Chuan Chen's response above in more depth in a fork of his code](https://github.com/mooreniemi/dot_product), I think the answer to this question should be: [use `ndarray` and `blas`](https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray#how-to-enable-blas-integration). It's 10x faster than the naive Rust implementation.

You can't see much here around `dot` because the heavy lifting is being done by including the `blas` feature for `ndarray`.

```rust
    let x = Array1::random(d, Uniform::<f32>::new(0., 1.));
    let y = Array1::random(d, Uniform::<f32>::new(0., 1.));

    for _i in 0..n {
        let _res: f32 = x.dot(&y);
    }
```

A couple things to note: 1. what's more representative than a dot product on one giant vector is many dot products on smaller vectors, since the `sum` should actually be counted per dot, and 2. it's going to be extremely hard to beat decades of linear algebra research packed into BLAS.